# An isomorphism of vector spaces is a homomorphism that admits a two sided inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Definition:  An isomorphism of vector spaces is a homomorphism that has a two sided inverse.**

Is the definition above in bold true?  It was mentioned in passing while discussing the solution to a problem in differential geometry but I couldn't find it anywhere in my old linear algebra book.

Edit:  The "definition" above isn't true.  What you **can** say is, existence two sided inverse for a map $f$ between vector spaces implies that $f$ is bijective.  But to show the rest of the statement is easy from that point.

Comment: homomorphism or homeomorphism?

Comment: Should have been homomorphism...someone edited it for me.

Comment: Sure, but what's a homomorphism of vector spaces? ;)

Comment: A homomorphism is a structure preserving map.

Comment: You need to check that the inverse is also a homomorphism.